# Efficient traversal/search algorithm to fetch data from RDF?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, rdf, sparql

I have my data as a RDF graph in DB and using SPARQL i am retriving the data. Now the nodes (objects) in the graphs gets huge and the traversal/search gets much slower now.

a. Can anyone suggest the efficient traversal/search algorithm to fetch the data?

As a next step, i have federated data i.e the data from external applications like SAP. In this case, the search becomes even much slower.

b. What efficient search algorithm do i use in this case?

This seems like a common issue in an large enterprise systems, and any inputs on how these problems have been solved in such systems will also be helpful.

Comment: Care to clarify what you're searching for and how you are currently doing it?  It's hard to suggest improvements without knowing what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem. I was doing a lot of graph traversal using SPARQL property paths and it was too slow using an RDF based repository. I was using Jena TDB which is supposed to be fast  but still it was too slow !

Like @Mikos suggested, I tried Neo4J. It then got much faster. Like Mark Watson says on [this blog entry](http://blog.markwatson.com/2010/12/nice-neo4j-version-12-final-released.html),

> RDF data stores support SPARQL queries: good for matching patterns in data.
>
> Neo4j supports arbitrary graph structures and seems best for exploring
> a neighborhood of a graph: start at a node and explore the connected
> nodes. (graph traversal)

I used Neo4j but you can try any tool that is built for graph traversal. I read that Allegrograph 4 is RDF based and has good graph traversal speed.

Now Im using Neo4j but I didnt give up on RDF. I still use URIs as identifiers and try to reuse the popular rdf vocabularies and relations. Later I'll add a feature to render my gaphs as RDF. I know that with Neo4j you can also use Tinkerpop to render RDF but I havent tried it myself.

Answer (score -1):

Graph traversal and efficient querying is a wide-ranging problem and the approach to use is dependent on your situation. I would suggest looking at a data-store like Neo4j and complementing it with a tool like Lucene.

Comment: could the downvoters care to elaborate? or just having a bad day?

Comment: I think it's because your answer isn't relevant to the OP's question, completely missing the parts where he mentions he's using RDF & SPARQL.

Comment: It is actually *very* relevant and was my topic of research. I was offering suggestions based on my experiences of combining Neo4J+lucene - that platform offered the most flexibility in overlaying multiple graph traversal algorithms.